# Can you help me whith "repeating-linear-gradient" I need the lines stand vertically inline like on the photo

Tags: css

Can you help me whith "repeating-linear-gradient"?

I currently have:

```css
    .myCSSrule {
         width:400px;
         height:400px;
         background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,dodgerblue 0% 
                 12.5%,mediumpurple 12.5% 25%,red 25% 50%, 
                 orange 50% 100% ,yellow,lime,mediumseagreen,deepskyblue);
    }
```

```html
<div class='myCSSrule'></div>
```

I need the lines standing vertically inline like on the below photo:

[image: here is how its supposed to be]

Comment: Having "i need...." in a title is not very fancy

Comment: @RamondeVries I agree, but I have done some heavy editing to the OPs question to improve it's readability....

Comment: what you have is not a repeating gradient

Comment: king_sumaru, look at your CSS; you are applying different widths to the different colour bands in your `background` CSS rule. you need to be consistent with these figures. You can [read the manual to help you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient()).